<Protect> of clerk component can not be used as jsx component after clerk upgrade core 2
I have a application which is using clerk . On upgradation core 2 of clerk. I am getting an error  component can not be used as jsx component. Without upgradation it's running successfully. But after, it get's me an error.
<Protect role="org:admin">  <CompanyButton /> </Protect> 

Type error: 'Protect' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element.
I have seen the official doc for update but didn't find anything. Now, I am expecting to get rid of this error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
